# What is the impact of multipath changes?

Tags: multipath-storage

I have work to do to install new paths in for multipath and I was asked if there could be an outage as a result of my work. I struggled to answer the question. Simply adding new aliases to multipath.conf and restarting the service should be no impact or outage.

However if I was to remove existing aliases in the multipath.conf file and restarted the service I am unsure what how the application would react to this change.

If the application is a database and is presented with the alias of the disk from multipath, does it use the alias all the time or will it translate that into the uuid. How would a database like Oracle react to removing or resetting the multipath.conf file to defaults.

Comment: Have you tested in a non-production system? Do you have a way to quickly and easily role-back?

Comment: If an application uses `/dev/mapper/mpatha`, and you make it disappear, it is likely that the application won't be amused. It's probably OK as long as the application doesn't use the pathname, for example to re-open that device. In the end it really depends on the application, but I would consider removing an alias highly risky.